# Cyrillic calligraphic font

Tags: fonts

I know how to write beautiful fonts in Latin, but I can't find Cyrillic.
[image]
Here are the various fonts: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{weva}
\begin{document}
    \weva{Hey!}
    %\weva{Привет}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use a modern OpenType, TrueType or Graphite font in LuaLateX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: The font style you are looking for is usually referred to as “script”. My suggestion would be to use `LuaLaTeX`, and simply use any font file on your system.

Comment: you can use any of these with lualatex or xelatex https://fonts.google.com/?category=Handwriting&subset=cyrillic

Comment: ParaType had a font mimicking Gogol's handwriting, I mean to recall it was free to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Miama Nueva](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/miama) handwriting font contains Cyrillic and has support for pdfLaTeX.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
The following is a text in the Miama Nueva font for pdf\LaTeX:

{\fontfamily{fmm}\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont
\begin{center}
Все люди рождаются свободными и равными в своем достоинстве 
и правах. Они наделены разумом и совестью и должны поступать 
в отношении друг друга в духе братства.
\end{center}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the text is copied from the Miama package documentation, no political statement intended.

Answer (score 3):

With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use any OpenType, TrueType or Graphite font on your system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newfontfamily\scrfamily{Segoe Script}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textscr}{\scrfamily}

\begin{document}
\scrfamily
Беручи до уваги, що визнання гідності, яка властива всім членам людскої сім'ї, і рівних та невід'ємних їх прав є основою свободі, справедливості та загального миру; і

беручи до уваги, що зневажання і нехтування правами людини призвели до варварських актів, які обурюють совість людства, і що створення такого світу, в якому люди будуть мати свободу слова і переконань і будуть вільні від страху і нужди, проголошено як високе прагнення людей; і
\end{document}
```

[image: Segoe Script sample]

This template defines `\scrfamily` and `\textscr` commands that work like `\ttfamily` or `\textsf`.

You can use any other font that supports Cyrillic, such as the free [Devroye Unicode](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Devroye).  If you think it looks strange for a script font to be so perfectly justified at the right margin, you might also want `\raggedright`.  If so, you might also want `\usepackage{parskip}` to separate paragraphs.

Unfortunately, searching for fonts based on whether they tag themselves as supporting a language is not very reliable, so you might instead get a list of font families that support Cyrillic with

```
albatross "U+0411"
```

Or any other Unicode character, especially one distinctive to the variant of Cyrillic you want.